# How to write the date in DatePicker without the day name?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

I'm using a DatePicker in WPF app and I'm trying to get the date with month name in arabic and without the name of day.

I'm following the documentation of DatePicker [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datepicker?view=netcore-3.1)

For example (image from the link of the documentation):

[image]

I would like to write the date without "Monday" and I prefer to get it in Arabic language,

Xaml Code:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDateFormat="Long" x:Name="EnteringDate" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Height="30" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" BorderBrush="White"/>
```

[image]

The desired output:

[image]

What I have tried , solution in StackOverflow but it does not work for me :

```
<DatePicker SelectedDateFormat="Long" x:Name="EnteringDate" Foreground="White" Background="Transparent" Height="30" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" BorderBrush="White">  <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                         Language="ar-EG"
                                         Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='yyyy MMM dd', 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: there is already question about custom date format in datepicker here ... also how to change culture info of the WPF app

Comment: But I need it in Arabic , that the difference between my question and the other question exist in StackOverflow

Comment: then set culture info to whole app ... how to do this? already asked, too

Comment: I'm trying this and it does not work for me

Comment: You didn't show in the question what had you tried

Comment: Please have a look again on my post , I have already made an update , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, i.e. set the `Language` of the `DatePicker` to some arabic culture and then optionally change the format using an implicit `DatePickerTextBox` style:

```
<DatePicker Language="ar-EG">
    <DatePicker.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='yyyy MMM dd', 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DatePicker.Resources>
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: What is Path=SelectedDate?

Comment: It's the property of the `DatePicker` control which stores the currently selected date.

Comment: I have tried the solution that you post but it does not work for me

Comment: The solution you have post, I mean there is any change , the DatePicker still show the old output

Comment: @abdou_dev: No, it doesn't, Then you haven't even managed to copy and paste my markup snippet...

Comment: I have already copied and used your code into the DatePicker element ,

Comment: Apparently you haven't if you don't see *any* difference. You won't get an English name when the `Language` property is set to "ar-EG".

Comment: I would like to get the date in arabic , I have already mentionned that in the post ( desired post )

Comment: ar-EG is Egyptian arabic.

Comment: Yes I know , I think that you don't understand what I need from the question posted

Comment: I think you don't know how to ask ... [it's working for me](http://selvin.pl/arabic.png)

Comment: @Selvin what I need exactly is get the date in arabic format , what I mean is for example instead of what is showen ( `Friday, September 2020,3`) I would like to get `سبتمبر 3 2020 `

Comment: That's what I get using this answer. Did you try to set the `Language` property of the `DatePicker` itself to "ar-EG"?

Comment: Yes for now it fixed  ( just add Language property to DatePicker , no need to add DatePicker Ressource ), so the first solution does not work for me , please change your last comment to a solution and I will accepted it

Comment: Post the comment as a new answer and I will marked it as an accepted answer

Comment: @abdou_dev: I edited it slightly but you seem to have downvoted it? Your edit was rejected by the system because of the pending edit from side by the way.

Comment: @abdou_dev: Reload the page by pressing F5 then. It says "edited 3 mins ago".